# What is the probability of randomly selecting n random numbers in the range 1-m in sorted order?

Tags: probability

For example say m is 10 and n is 3. I am selecting 3 numbers from 1-10 and want to know the probability with which they will be in sorted order. 1, 1, 4 would be fine. 1, 6, 3 would not be fine. For m=10 and n=2, the probability of selecting the 2 numbers in sorted order is 55/100.

How could I calculate the probability for any arbitrary n and m?

Comment: Have you tried simulating?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How would I do that?

Comment: Is the sampling without replacement? I ask because in that case there's a simple solution: each sequence $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and its five permutations are equally likely and exactly one is in sorted order, whence the answer is $1/6$ ($1/n!$ in general). If you're sampling *with* replacement, an answer can similarly be derived but becomes combinatorially more complex.

Comment: with replacement

Comment: Do you know any programming? What statistical software do you use? It should be pretty easy to code something like this up in R, MATLAB, or Python. I don't deny that there will be an analytical solution, but I'm not good enough to derive it.

Comment: I believe there is a fairly simply recursive relation that solves this elegantly.  It would be pretty easy to code it, not as a simulation but as a computational means to exactly solve it with recursive functions.  But are you looking for a closed form solution?  That probably exists too but I'm not sure how to derive it from the recursion.

Comment: Actually, looking at this a bit closer, we have `p(2,n) = (1/n) + (n-1/n)(1/2)`.  From here, try expanding the formula for p(3,n) using recursion.  The formula you get involves computing harmonic numbers.  It's known that that there is no closed form solution to this problem, which leads me to believe there is no closed form solution here either.  Writing a program to compute exact answers should still be relatively easy, however.

Comment: @Jonah There *is* a closed formula: it is $\frac{(-1)^m (-n)^{(m)}}{m^{n} n (m-1)!}$, where the $(m)$ refers to a *factorial power,* $x^{(m)} = x(x-1)\cdots(x-m+1)$. For example, with $m=10,$ $n=3$ we obtain $\frac{(-1)^{10} (-3)^{(10)}}{10^3 3 (10-1)!}$ = $220/1000$ = $0.22$.

Comment: @whuber, cool, and nice bump :)

Answer (score 6):

David's answer is incorrect because they are not i.i.d. The probability the nth draw is greater than all previous draws and the probability the n-1th draw is greater than all previous draws are not independent.

Here is some python code to calculate the exact probability recursively:

```
# Recursively finds the number of combinations that are in order for n draws
# of random integers from 1 to m.
def recursively_find_combinations(m,n):
    if n==2: # For the n=2 case just return the sum from 1 to m
        return float(m*(m+1))/2
    else: # Otherwise sum from 1 to m the ordered combinations when n = n-1
        return sum([recursively_find_combinations(x,n-1) for x in range(1,m+1)])

# Finds the probability that n draws n draws of random integers from 1 to m will be in order.
def find_p(m,n):
    return recursively_find_combinations(m,n)/(m**n)
```

Let's break it down by the number of combinations of draws that are in order and how many combinations are possible.

There are $m^n$ possible combinations.

Let's start by looking at m=10 and n=2. There are 100 combinations ($10^2$). How many are in order? There are 10 combinations where the first number is a 1, all 10 of these will be in order because the second number will be greater than or equal to 1. There are 10 combinations where the first number is a 2, 9 of these will be in order, only 1 is eliminated, the combination (2,1). Following this reasoning there are 10 + 9 + 8 + ... + 1 or  $=\sum_{x=1}^{x=m}x = \frac{(m)(m+1)}{2} = 55 $ ordered combinations. There are 100 possible combinations so that gives a $=\frac{55}{100} = .55$ probability of getting an ordered result.

So for n = 2 the ordered combinations are $=\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_1=m}x_1$.

Now let's look at m=10 and n=3. There are 1000 possible combinations ($10^3$).

There are 100 combinations that start with a 1. The number that are in order (55) are the same as the ordered combinations for m=10 and n=2 because all numbers are greater or equal to 1. There are 100 combinations that start with a 2. There are 45 combinations that are in order, the same 55 as when it started with a 1 minus the 10 combinations of the form 2,1,x. None of those are in order because 1 is smaller than 2 no matter what x is. When we start with a 3 there are 55-10-9 ordered combinations. Do this all the way up to 10. Starting with a 10 there are 55-10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1 ordered combinations.

So the total number of ordered combinations for m=10 and n=3 is $\sum_{x_2=1}^{x_2=m}\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_1=x_2}x_1$.

Following this reasoning the total number of combinations for an arbitrary n and m is $\sum_{x_{n-1}=1}^{x_{n-1}=m}\sum_{x_{n-2}=1}^{x_{n-2}=x_{n-1}}\sum_{x_{n-3}=1}^{x_{n-3}=x_{n-2}}...\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_1=x_2}x_1$.

To find the probability of drawing an ordered combination just divide the number of ordered combinations by the possible combinations.

$=\frac{\sum_{x_{n-1}=1}^{x_{n-1}=m}\sum_{x_{n-2}=1}^{x_{n-2}=x_{n-1}}\sum_{x_{n-3}=1}^{x_{n-3}=x_{n-2}}...\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_1=x_2}x_1}{m^n}$

Some results for m = 10 while varying n:

```
P(ordered|m=10,n=2)=    0.55000000
P(ordered|m=10,n=3)=    0.22000000
P(ordered|m=10,n=4)=    0.07150000
P(ordered|m=10,n=5)=    0.02002000
P(ordered|m=10,n=6)=    0.00500500
P(ordered|m=10,n=7)=    0.00114400
P(ordered|m=10,n=8)=    0.00024310
P(ordered|m=10,n=9)=    0.00004862
```

Comment: In all for m=10 that computes to (n+9)!/9!/n!/10^n. (n+m-1)!/(m-1)!/n!/m^n for the general case.

Answer (score 3):

#### Recursive Solution

Let the first number chosen be $k$ (with probability $1/m$).  The chance that all are in order now equals the chance that the remaining $n-1$ are (a) in order and (b) equal or exceed $k$.  Subtracting $k-1$ from all of the remaining numbers puts them in one-to-one correspondence with the possible ways of selecting numbers in order from $1, 2, \ldots, m-k+1$; according to part (b), this chance has to be multiplied by $(m-k+1)^{n-1}$.  Letting $p(n,m)$ denote the chance, this provides the recursion

$$p(n,m) = \frac{1}{m}\sum _{k=1}^m \left(\frac{m-k+1}{m}\right)^{n-1} p(n-1,m-k+1),$$

with $p(1,m)=1$ to get it started.

**The unique solution is**

$$p(n,m) = \frac{(n+1)^{[m-1]}}{m^n(m-1)!}$$

where "$^{[m]}$" denotes an *ascending factorial power*; in general,

$$x^{[m]} = x(x+1) \cdots (x+m-1).$$

To verify the solution we need only to show it satisfies the recursion and the initial condition; this is a matter of algebraic checking.

For instance, with $n=3, m=10$ we obtain

$$p(3,10) =\frac{(3+1)^{[10-1]}}{10^3(10-1)!} = \frac{4\cdot 5\cdots 11 \cdot 12 }{10^3 (9 \cdot 8 \cdots 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)} = \frac{10 \cdot11\cdot 12}{10^3(3\cdot2\cdot1)}=\frac{11}{50}=0.22.$$

---

#### Combinatorial Solution

A selection of $n$ values (with repetition) from the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots, m\}$ is a sequence $(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n)$.  Such sequences are in one-to-one correspondence with the sequences $(k_1, k_2+1, \ldots, k_n + n-1)$ drawn from the numbers $\{1, 2, \ldots, m+n-1\}$.  (For instance, drawing $(1,1,4)$ from $1..10$ would correspond to drawing $(1,2,6)$ from $1..12$.)  Moreover, the original sequence is in order if and only if the derived sequence is in *strict* order.  It thereby determines (and is determined by) the subset $\{k_1, k_2+1, \ldots, k_n+n-1\}$, of which there are $\binom{n+m-1}{n}$ possibilities (by definition).  Because there are $m^n$ equally probable sequences, **the desired probability is**

$$p(n,m) = m^{-n}\binom{n+m-1}{n}.$$

This of course is just another way to express the previous formula for $p(n,m)$ (or, if you like, equating the two results gives us an explicit formula for the binomial coefficient!).

For example,

$$p(3, 10) = 10^{-3}\binom{3+10-1}{3} = 10^{-3}\binom{12}{3} = \frac{12\cdot 11\cdot 10}{10^3(3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)} = \frac{11}{50},$$

exactly as determined with the recursive solution.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I got something wrong, I think it might me possible to bring down you $n,m$ problem to a $2,n$ problem, which you have resolved for $n=10$ and of which the solution is more generally $p = \frac{n+1}{2n}$

$P[X_m \ge X_{m-1} \ge ... \ge X_1]=$

$P[X_m \ge \max (X_{m-1},X_{m-2}  ...  X_1);X_{m-1} \ge \max (X_{m-2},X_{m-3}  ...  X_1);...X_1 \ge \max(X_1)=X_1]$

Because they are $i.i.d$ this makes it:

$=P[X_m \ge \max (X_{m-1},X_{m-2}  ...  X_1]P[X_{m-1} \ge \max (X_{m-2},X_{m-3}  ...  X_1]... P[X_1 \ge \max(X_1)=X_1]$

$=\prod_{i=1}^{i=m-1} P[X_m \ge X_{i}] \prod_{i=1}^{i=m-2} P[X_{m-1} \ge X_{i}]\prod_{i=1}^{i=m-(m-1)} P[X_{2} \ge X_{i}]$

where $P_{i\not=j}[X_i \ge X_j] = \frac{n+1}{2n}$